# Parsing a complicated HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, html, domdocument, domxpath

I successfully parsed a dynamic table with the following PHP code:

```
$docH = new DOMDocument();
$docH->loadHTMLFile($url);

//get everything inside the body element:
$bodyH = $docH->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

foreach ($bodyH->childNodes as $childNode) {
       echo $docH->saveHTML($childNode);
}
```

Parsed HTML Table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>5CG</td>
        <td>aass</td>
        <td>sxs</td>
        <td>sx</td>
        <td>EK</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>72</td>
    </tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>samplxs</td>
    <td>xs</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>xss</td>
    <td>fkxsx aus</td>
    <td>s</td>
    </tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>5AH.</td>
    <td>ds</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>sdf</td>
    <td>sdfsdf aus</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6CG</td>
        <td>3.</td>
        <td>sfd</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>scs</td>
        <td>das aus</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7DG</td>
        <td>6.</td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>sD</td>
        <td>sdsa.</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>samplxs</td>
    <td>xs</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>xss</td>
    <td>fkxsx aus</td>
    <td>s</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7DG, 7CG, 7CR</td>
        <td>6.</td>
        <td>NsdR</td>
        <td>s</td>
        <td>SP</td>
        <td>fasdlt aus</td>
        <td>s</td>
    </tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>samplxs</td>
    <td>xs</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>xss</td>
    <td>fkxsx aus</td>
    <td>s</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9BR</td>
        <td>6.</td>
        <td>FEI</td>
        <td>sa</td>
        <td>DE</td>
        <td>fasdad aus</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9AR, 9BR, 9CR</td>
        <td>62.</td>
        <td>BEH</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>sd</td>
        <td>fasda aus</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>6.</td>
        <td>MLR</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>FdR</td>
        <td>fsdfaus</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E10C</td>
        <td>6.</td>
        <td>sdf</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>fsdfs aus</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
```

But my goal is to just show the content of the table the user wants by asking for just the `<tr>` elements in which the first `<td>` of the first `<tr>` includes some text until there is another `<tr>` which first `<td>` has a different content.

For example: If the user types "9BR" into an input field, I just want him to see:

9BR
6.
FEI
sa
DE
fasdad aus



    9AR, 9BR, 9CR
    62.
    BEH
    
    sd
    fasda aus
    


    
    6.
    MLR
    
    FdR
    fsdfaus

If he types in 5CG:

```
<tr>
    <td>5CG</td>
    <td>aass</td>
    <td>sxs</td>
    <td>sx</td>
    <td>EK</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>72</td>
</tr>
<td></td>
<td>samplxs</td>
<td>xs</td>
<td></td>
<td>xss</td>
<td>fkxsx aus</td>
<td>s</td>
</tr>
```

Or if 6CG just:

```
<tr>
    <td>6CG </td>
    <td>3. </td>
    <td>sfd </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>scs </td>
    <td>das aus</td>
    <td>a </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use XPath expressions to get what you want.

Comment: wow that was quick, thank you, I'm gonna look it up

Comment: how do I select a `<td> </td>` that is empty or **ONLY** includes white spaces no matter how many?

Answer (score 2):

Using XPath, something like this should do the trick
http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

```
$xpath = new DomXpath($docH);
$trs = $xpath->query('//tr[td[1][contains(text(), "BR9")]]');
```

> find all tr which first td contains text "anything"

as for the following ´tr´s with empty first `td`
this might not be the most elegant form to query this, but would work:

```
$query = '
//tr[td[1][contains(text(), "anything")]]
 |
//tr[td[1][contains(text(), "anything")]]
     /following-sibling::tr[td[1][not(text())] and preceding-sibling::tr[1][td[1][not(text()) or contains(text(), "anything")]]]
';
```

> find all tr which first td contains text "anything"
>
> also find all tr which first td is empty **and** whose preceding siblings (trs) first td
>   is also empty or contains text "anything"

example: http://3v4l.org/q6eDu

Comment: great! but how do I add the following tr elements without text inside their first td elements between the one and the one that has other text inside their first td!?
eg: 5CG example

Comment: I'm fascinated! Thanks a lot!
Last thing: how can I echo the html result?

Comment: `foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $res) {
    var_dump($doc->saveHTML($res));
}` - you're welcome :)

Comment: sometimes the following empty "<td> </td>" elements that I want to include contain one or sometimes even more whitespaces and not just nothing… I tried to add this but it didn't work out. Some idea how to change it!? I thought about maybe regex can help here.